# Travel tips for grandparents

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> My grandparents are pretty specific about which places they deem appropriate for visiting.
>
> In the UK, they've liked pretty much every place they've visited. They cherish Edinburgh and Liverpool, and worship Birmingham.
>
> In America, their opinions are a bit more mixed. They fancy Boston and care for Washington, but dislike New York and avoid Chicago altogether.
>
> They treasure the memory of their time in Paris, but detest France in general.
>
> They fancy Tokyo, but resent Beijing and absolutely abhor Hong Kong.

Next, my grandparents want to visit Central Europe. Do you think they're more likely to have a good time in **Berlin**, **Zurich** or **Vienna**?

Comment: Featuring a cameo of the user whose puzzles inspired this.

Comment: Liverpool, to Hope Street, the only street in the world with a cathedral at both ends, you might not like one but the other is astounding. The parks, Sefton and Calderstones and a dozen others. The waterfront from the Pier Head to Otterspool, past the Garden Festival site. Yes, I am biased, but I genuinely feel Liverpool is the most beautiful. - it would have to be something with Liverpool

Comment: also you can use these to understand the places: https://www.buzzfeed.com/tomphillips/toms-of-york

Comment: @DeerSpotter I'm sure if these were real people, they would appreciate the travel recommendations! This is a puzzle, though, so the preferences are likely based on letters or pronunciation rather than the actual locations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> They will probably like **Zurich**, but not the others. The pattern appears to be that they look favorably on locations in which the first syllable of the name is spoken with stronger emphasis than the others.